# get Actor hit() from array of Nodes

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have an array of nodes, i need to get a specific `Node` from this array in the `InputListener` event using Actor hit()..

I have multiple menu items (Buttons, Levels) but the touch event not working.
This is what i tried so far:

```
 public Actor hit(final float x, final float y, final boolean b) {
    ...
        for (int i = this.nodesList.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            final Node node = this.nodesList.get(i);
            if (node instanceof SpriteNode) {
                SpriteNode newNode = (SpriteNode) node;
                if  (newNode.anchornsform.det() != 0.0f) {
                    final Affine2 inv = newNode.anchoreansform.inv();
                  ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return myactor;
}
```

Please help, if you have a better solution I'm open to any suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: First of all, you don't need to call `node != null` after you checked it with `instanceof` (if it would be null instanceof would return false). Second, you're casting your `Node` object to `SpriteNode` 3 times. Don't. Assign it to a pointer like `if(node instanceof SpriteNode) SpriteNode newNode = (SpriteNode) node;` and use the `newNode` later. Third, I don't know what do you want to achieve. Please explain your question a bit. We don't even know if your code works now or not ;)

Comment: my code returns null

Comment: @spectre I have multiple menu items (Buttons, Levels) but the touch event not working for me

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote in the comment, your `hit()` is returning `null`

This part:

```
} else {
        for (int i = nodesList.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            final Node node = nodesList.get(i);
            if (node instanceof SpriteNode) {
                if (node != null && ((SpriteNode)node).anchoredAffineWorldTransform.det() != 0.0f) {
                    final Affine2 inv = ((SpriteNode)node).anchoredAffineWorldTransform.inv();
                    if (((SpriteNode)node).hit(inv.m00 * x + inv.m01 * y + inv.m02, inv.m10 * x + inv.m11 * y + inv.m12, b) != null) {
                        myactor= node;
                        return myactor;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

can't return `null` - cause it just can't.

So either `myactor = super.hit(x, y, b);` is causing null or `else` isn't fired at all and you have `null` cause nothing was assigned to `myactor`.

Comment: the touch event still not working

Comment: Check with debugger and breakpoints if this line: `if (newNode.hit(inv.m00 * x + inv.m01 * y + inv.m02, inv.m10 * x + inv.m11 * y + inv.m12, b) != null) {` is ever fired. If it is - it's the bugged line.

Comment: no its not fired, please check this pic : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awg5j.png

Comment: Sorry @spectre the line `myactor= node;` is the one not fired

Comment: To be 100% clear, you have your error here: `inv.m00 * x + inv.m01 * y + inv.m02, inv.m10 * x + inv.m11 * y + inv.m12, b`. Check it again. I can't do anything cause I don't even know how these parameters should work.

Comment: If the answer helped you and solved the problem - mark it as complete and up-vote if you want to! :) 

Noproblem!